# How do I setblock at the location of an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I was trying out [MrGarettos Command Combiner](https://mrgarretto.com/cmdcombiner)
I wanted to place a fire block at 2 items which they are...

Netherrack and Flint and steel.

**But the question is how do I do /setblock at an item??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should work.

```
execute @e[type=item,(some other condition like name or specific item)] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ fire
```

Comment: I want to look for more than one item though, I want to look for Netherrack and Flint and Steel together.